# simple programmatic modification of a single IB constraint not updating

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

EDIT: It seems i need to change the multiplier and not the constant.

I'm trying to programmatically change the width of a button outside of viewDidLoad (if that matters) after a certain event has taken place.

I've set the buttons width in IB to equal the Views width.

I've created a IB outlet for the buttons width constraint:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageButtonWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then I've tried:

```
 imageButtonWidth.constant = 0.49
    view.setNeedsLayout()
```

,

```
 imageButtonWidth.constant = 0.49
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

and

```
imageButtonWidth.constant = 0.49
    self.view.updateConstraints()
```

I've set a breakpoint at imageButtonWidth.constant = 0.49 and it crashes the app so I know its being "ran" it's just not activating correctly.

I've used

```
imageButtonWidth.constant = 0.49
    self.view.updateConstraints()
```

in viewdidload on a different application with no issue, but it seems if the call is outside viewdidload it won't be acknowledged.

any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A width constant of 0.49 would give you a button less than one point wide. Are you sure that's the right value? Are you seeing any constraint errors in the console?

Comment: no theres no error. its a little less than half the view, where totally equal widths of the button to view would  be a constant of 1. Thanks for the response!

Comment: You're mistaking the constant with the multiplier, I think. You can't change the multiplier.

Comment: Yes you're right, there has to be a way to change it though.

Comment: You have to inactivate the constraint, create a new one, and activate that.

Comment: I'll look into that thanks.

Comment: Are you forced to update the multiplier value? Are you able to *compute* the constant for a multiplier of 0.49? Another option: Could you create a second constraint with the multiplier in IB, set it to a lower priority, then create an IBOutlet for it. Then you just need to alter priorities without deactivating things.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it is with

```
 self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

to update the constraint but you probably connected a wrong outlet it seems since the value of the constraint seems to low.

Comment: ah wow, i just looked back at my IB, i actually need to change the multiplier, and not the constant. but it seems like the multiplier is read only.

Comment: cool so if you managed to solve your problem like that you should answer you own question so others can see the solution as well. If not ... the way you change constrains is by playing with the constant and assining it a new value and then run self.view.layoutIfNeeded()